# How to copy part of texture to an image in opengl

Tags: opengl, image-processing, textures, bmp, image-rotation

Im working on a porject in opengl. 
I have a polygon in the polygon filled with bmp image file.
I can rotate the camera to look at the image from different places, and I want to copy the part of the image and put it inside a new bmp file.
I have alot of Unnecessary code so I will copy the imprtant parts.

```
_textureId = LoadBMP("file.bmp");


glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glColor3f(1, 1, 0.7);
float BOX_SIZE = -12.0f;
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, -5);
glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, -5);
glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, 5);
glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, 5);


glEnd();
```

and the rotation is pretty basic, soo someone have any suggestions?
thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the output of OpenGL to a file, you will have to read back the contents of the color buffer from the GL to client memory. Then, you can do whatecver you want to it. The command

[`glReadPixels`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)`(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLvoid *data`)

will read back the pixel data in an rectangle of the `width` * `height` pixels beginning at `x`,`y` to the memory buffer located at `data`. Since you said you want to save it as a BMP file, you probably want `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as type, because BMP only supports up to 8 bit per channel. You also want probably `GL_BGA` or `GL_BGR` as the format, as this is the native channel layout for BMP.

Comment: thanks foe the quick answer. but in what format do I save the data? is it char** or what? sorry about my knowledge but im realy new to this subject.

Comment: Well. If you want to save it as BMP, you probably should use some kind of image library. Windows itself should also by able to produce BMP files. Basically, you will need a pendant to your `LoadBitmap` function.